# Input Type Hidden Fields in a foreach loop

Tags: php, types, input, foreach, hidden

I'm trying to add submit buttons and hidden input fields so that when a user clicks a submit button I can identify the item they selected. Although I can't figure out how to access the hidden values. I have this code (the value in input type="hidden" are the item's id's). How do I access the values?

```
foreach($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM beer WHERE country_id = $countryID") as $beer) {
    echo "<a href='BeerSummary.php?beerID=$beer[id]'>$beer[2]</a> <br/>";
    echo "ABV $beer[3]% - $beer[4] ml - Case Size $beer[5] - Price £$beer[6]";
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"> <br/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="beer_id[]" value="'.$beer[0].'">';
    echo "<br/>";
```

}

```
if(isset($_POST["beer_id"])) {
//
}
```

Comment: Are you using a form or a link to submit the data?  I can't see a form tag, only an anchor tag.

Comment: <form action="" method="POST"> and </form> tags are in my code, didn't include it as this is just a small part of the code that I'm having the trouble with

Comment: Is the FORM-tag outside the loop or inside the loop for each element?

Comment: Outside, oh I see where this is going - put it inside?

Comment: Yeah. Then you get one post including only what you want to add to cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have them defined as an input array, so the way to access it/them would be:

```
foreach($_POST['beer_id'] as $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Hm, though that gives me all values and not the one the user submits - any other way?

Comment: If you have all of those in one form, then they'll all get submitted. The best way if you want to do one at a time would be to split each into a mini form, and take the array off the input.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. Would it be better to have several mini forms or to use some kind of variable counter for the name of each hidden input and use multiple if isset statements to check which has been submitted and get the value that way?

Comment: If you are only doing one at a time - I'd stick to separate forms. If you're doing more than one at a time, I'd use jQuery to populate a comma delimited array into one single hidden element and then explode that into an array once it's posted.

Comment: I'm doing it one at a time so I'll stick to several forms, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

for each of hidden fields, take id. `id = hidden + $beer[i]`
then u can easily access the hidden fields with `document.getElementById("hidden" + $beer[i])`

this will work in javascript.

if u want to so the same in php, @Ben's answer should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, though I'll be sticking to PHP for this :)